# Select data from JSON populated table to open hidden div including related JSON data in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I'm trying to create a single page app (using ng-sho and ng-hide) displaying buildings. Currently, my code looks like this

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <title>Happy Building Company</title>
</head>


<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">     
<!--BUILDING DIRECTORY-->
    <div id="directory" class="mainDiv" ng-show="buildingDirVisible">
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Building Directory</legend>
        <div id="directoryTable" style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <table class="table table-responsive" id="dirtable">
        <tr>
          <th>Building ID</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>View</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowHover" ng-repeat="item in buildings" >
          <td> {{item.ID}}</td>
          <td> {{item.Owner}}</td>
          <td> {{item.Address}}</td>
          <td> <button type="button" value="View Building" ng-click="viewBuilding()">View Building</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.name = 'Happy Building Company';

$scope.buildings = null;
$scope.target1 = '/building_dir.json';

$scope.building = $http.get($scope.target1)
.then(
  function successCall(response) {
    $scope.buildings = response.data.buildings;
  },
  function errorCall(response) {
    $scope.feedback = "Error reading building directory";
    $scope.buildings = null; 
  }
);

//View Building - NEED TO WORK OUT HOW TO SPECIFY TO A BUILDING
$scope.viewbuilding = function(){
  $scope.buildingDirVisible = false;
  $scope.buildingFormVisible = true; // Building form visible
};
```

building_dir.json

```
{"buildings":[{"ID":"123",
               "Owner":"Joe Doe",
               "Address":"20 Lambton Quay",
               "BuildingType":null,
               "ConstructionDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
              },
              {"ID":"222",
               "Owner":"John Smith",
               "Address":"20 Dixon Street",
               "BuildingType":null,
               "ConstructionDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
              }]}
```

I am trying to have it so that when you select View Building in the table in the building directory that the buildingDirVisible div is hidden and another div is opened displaying information only related to that building ID (ie. Building ID 222's Building Type and Construction date). Currently, my app switches between the divs using show and hide but does not display data specific details. My understanding is that I will have to develop a for loop to iterate through the JSON file and then display buildings that match the building ID. I am relatively new to angular js so any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some observations as per your code review** **:**

- `$scope.viewbuilding = function() { ... }` should be `$scope.viewBuilding = function() { ... }` as in view we are triggering `viewBuilding` not `viewbuilding`.
- Div having `buildingFormVisible` is not available in the view where you want to display the data specific to building ID that you selected from the table.

Your approach is correct !!

You can loop to iterate through the buildings `JSON` and then display buildings that match the building ID.

For this approach, you can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method with `ES6` Arrow operator.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.buildingDirVisible = true;
    $scope.buildingFormVisible = false;
    $scope.buildings = [{"ID":"123",
               "Owner":"Joe Doe",
               "Address":"20 Lambton Quay",
               "BuildingType":null,
               "ConstructionDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
              },
              {"ID":"222",
               "Owner":"John Smith",
               "Address":"20 Dixon Street",
               "BuildingType":null,
               "ConstructionDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
              }];
              
    //View Building - NEED TO WORK OUT HOW TO SPECIFY TO A BUILDING
 $scope.viewBuilding = function(itemID) {
    $scope.buildingDirVisible = false;
    $scope.buildingFormVisible = true; // Building form visible
    var record = $scope.buildings.filter(item => { return item.ID == itemID });
    $scope.buildingDetail = record[0];
  };          
});
```

```css
table,tr,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <table class="table table-responsive" id="dirtable" ng-show="buildingDirVisible">
        <tr>
          <th>Building ID</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>View</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowHover" ng-repeat="item in buildings" >
          <td> {{item.ID}}</td>
          <td> {{item.Owner}}</td>
          <td> {{item.Address}}</td>
          <td> <button type="button" value="View Building" ng-click="viewBuilding(item.ID)">View Building</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div ng-show="buildingFormVisible">
      <p>Building ID : {{buildingDetail.ID}}</p>
      <p>Building ID : {{buildingDetail.Owner}}</p>
      <p>Building ID : {{buildingDetail.Address}}</p>
      <p>Building ID : {{buildingDetail.ConstructionDate}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That perfectly displays the data. If I wanted to add a return button would that be as simple as adding <button type="button" value="Return" ng-click="return())">Return</button> in my HTML and then having $scope.viewBuilding = function(itemID) {
    $scope.buildingDirVisible = true;
    $scope.buildingFormVisible = false;} in my app.js?

Comment: @EmmaO'Neill Please mark it correct so that it will be useful for other users as well.